# How can you use python variables in an sql search

Tags: python, sql

For my program I need to link two tables together which I know how to do. However, I only need to select certain fields and they are already stored in a python variable. How can I execute an sql search with only selects the fields from the row containing that variable value?

I am using SQLite and all I can do at the moment is something like

```
sql1 = '''SELECT *
FROM Dogs INNER JOIN Owners
ON Dogs.DogID = Owners.DogID
Order By Speed desc;
'''
```

I need to be able to use a variable

Comment: What API are you using to execute SQL from within Python? Can you share some code here?

Comment: Where you want to put the variable?

Comment: I want to have it selecting where the DogID is equal to the one saved in my variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python manuals should be the primary information source. The standard library directly provides a Sqlite interface with nice examples.

One example just reads as:

```
# Never do this -- insecure!
symbol = 'RHAT'
c.execute("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol = '%s'" % symbol)

# Do this instead
t = ('RHAT',)
c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?', t)
print c.fetchone()
```

With your own code, it gives:

```
sql1 = '''SELECT *
FROM Dogs INNER JOIN Owners
ON Dogs.DogID = Owners.DogID
WHERE Dogs.DogID = ?
Order By Speed desc;
'''
c.execute(sql1, dogid)
...
```

Comment: I get an error message when specifying variable above that then using what you said as apparently it uses 1 binding but 7 are supplied

Comment: @BenDent Is `DogID` a string of 7 characters? Then you most probably forgot to provide it as a 1-tuple, ie. `c.execute(sql1, (dogid,))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can search in a SQL database like this:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('db.sq3')
cursor = db.cursor()

to_search = ('value', )
found = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE key=?', to_search).fetchall()
```

Comment: @Serge: That's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

A little example of string formatting in python:

```
sql1 = '''SELECT * {0}
FROM {1} INNER JOIN {2}
ON {1}.{3} = {2}.{3}
Order By {4} desc;
'''

print(sql1.format('Spot','Dogs', 'Owners', 'DogID', 'Speed'))
```